# Understanding hashing for 'removal' of personal information

Tags: hash, sha256

Say you do a survey among students at a university.

The survey returns their email address together with their answers to your questions.

Now you have another dataset which links the email addresses to what they are studying, at which faculty, etc. This is information you'd like to combine with the answers, so that you can analyse if answers differ for different faculties, etc.

However, from a privacy point of view, it's important that the email addresses disappear from the datasets.

One simple method for keeping the link while getting rid of the email addresses, is to hash the addresses using the same algorithm on both sets. Then the email addresses can be deleted. However, is this actually protecting the student's privacy all that well?

Would someone be able to 'hack' this simply by guessing which hashing algorithm you have used (for example sha256), and then running all student email addresses (which are publicly known) through the algorithm?

Comment: I'm not a security expert, far from it, but I think your last paragraph is a fair point. However, you may be able to mitigate that by using a seed that is only known to the hasher, and perhaps randomly generated. As far as I understood, it is only needed once, and there is no need to generate the hashes again and again (which would be the case for, e.g., a password).

Comment: If you already have both datasets, can't you combine both datasets immediately, then throw away the e-mail addresses? It's just an id-number between the two datasets, really. (Of course, other information between the two datasets may be used to identify people, but as far as the e-mail addresses is concerned, you can get rid of those immediately when combining the two datasets.)

Comment: Note that there is also https://security.stackexchange.com/ ; I'm not entirely sure if this question fits their domain, but it may be worth a try for more responses.